# API.AI: There is a way to say that a word is more important to consider in an intent?

Tags: chatbot, dialogflow-es

I would like to know if we can define key words priority in an intent. In fact I had a problem with the proper identification of the intent.  I have 3 intents:

- Book a room
- List my reservations
- Cancel my reservation

I said: "List reservation" without "S".

- Expected behavior:  "List my reservations"
- Actual behavior  :  "Cancel my reservation"

So there is a way to say that the word "list" is more important than the word "reservations " when choosing the intent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there isn't a way to define the priority of Entities (yet) on api.ai.  But the problem you're encountering can be solved by creating two **Intents**, one would be `CancelReservation` and another `ListReservation`. Then you can give example inputs such for both, such as, for `ListReservation`, the **User says** section will have:

"List all my reservations"
"Show me a list of all my reservations"
"I want to see a list of my reservations"
"Give me a list of my reservations"

And so on.You can then give similar example inputs for `CancelReservation`. It should work fine by now, but in case it makes any mistakes, just go to **Training** and map those to the correct Intents, and it'll work as expected.